How to run pass with clang
I have written a compiler pass, which needs to change IR, and I want to use it in Clang.
It works well when I use:
opt -load=/home/yyb/Desktop/test/libinsertca.so -passes=Insertca -S test.ll -o test2.ll

But when I want to use the frontend command "clang", such as
clang -Xclang -load -Xclang ...so -Xclang -passes=Insertca

or
clang -fpass-plugin=....so

it doesn't change the IR, its like there never has my pass.
What command should I use to compile a C file with my pass by Clang?
My clang version is:
clang version 20.0.0git (https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project.git f2f9cdd22171f0c54cad7c6b183857f3d856c344)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/local/bin


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works and read "[ask]". Then come back and [edit] your question to enhance it.

I have formatted and reworded your question in the hope it shows your issue a bit clearer. Please check it and correct, if necessary.

Please extent the example command lines that do not work to the complete form.

You tried -Xclang -load -Xclang ...so (does not work). Have you tried -Xclang -load=...so?
